# How to merge two dataframe of same column name side by side [For example, A will be next to A]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, combinations

I have two dataframe with similar columns, and I want to merge them.

Dataset for example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': ["abc", "abc"], 'C': [0, 1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 6], 'B': ["bcd", "abc"], 'C': [5, 5]})
```

I used the code:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

which returns

```
    A   B   C   A   B   C
0   1   abc 0   1   bcd 5
1   2   abc 1   6   abc 5
```

Expected format

```
    A   A   B   B   C   C 
0   1   1   abc bcd 0   5
1   2   6   abc abc 1   5
```

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can sort the columns (with a stable sort so that df1's columns come first):

```py
>>> pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).sort_index(axis="columns", kind="stable")

   A  A    B    B  C  C
0  1  1  abc  bcd  0  5
1  2  6  abc  abc  1  5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) after the `concat`:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1, kind='stable')
```

Or, if you don't want to sort, concat vertically adding an extra level and [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
pd.concat(dict(enumerate([df1, df2]))).unstack(-1).droplevel(axis=1, level=1)
```

Output:

```
   A  A    B    B  C  C
0  1  1  abc  bcd  0  5
1  2  6  abc  abc  1  5
```